# ASP.NET Core: SignUp Button with OpenID Connect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, keycloak, openid-connect

I have an asp.net core application where I use open id connect authentication via keycloak. The authentication is configured as follows:

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    // URL of the Keycloak server
    options.Authority = Configuration["Oidc:Authority"];
    // Client configured in the Keycloak
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Oidc:ClientId"];

    // For testing we disable https (should be true for production)
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Env.IsProduction();

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    // Client secret shared with Keycloak
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Oidc:ClientSecret"];
    // options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    // OpenID flow to use
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
});
```

Normal Sign in / Sign out work fine, I can also register a new user by clicking "register" from keycloaks sign in form.

Now I want to have a "sign up" button directly in my application. This button should not lead to the log in form, but to keycloaks registration form.

I found this mail: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-August/007473.html

But I cannot figure out how to configure the parameters in such a way, that it works.